# Регулярное выражение - цифры и дефис

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите регулярку такого вида:

Нужно валидировать такую запись: `9999999-9999999-9999999`.

Либо вместо дефиса - пробел.

Comment: Количество групп фиксировано? количество цифр в каждой группе - фиксировано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[0-9]{7}[ -][0-9]{7}[ -][0-9]{7}
```

или

```
\d{7}[ -]\d{7}[ -]\d{7}
```

что то же самое.
Или

```
(\d{7}[ -]){2}\d{7}
```

что то же самое.

Comment: Благодарю вас, это работает